# How to match the first word of a line and separate subsequent values with a comma

Tags: python, regex, ruby, pattern-matching

I'm stuck with a problem: I have over one hundred different markdown files and need to update a single line of frontmatter in them. In the `tags:` line, I need to wrap the values in brackets and separate them by a comma. There's hundreds of different values, so there's not really a pattern there.

Here's an example:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Blog title"
date: 2016-02-24 09:39:00 -0500
tags: work career code programming
layout: post
---
```

And it needs to look something like:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Blog title"
date: 2016-02-24 09:39:00 -0500
tags: ["work", "career", "code", "programming"]
layout: post
---
```

I'm not sure the best way to do this. I've only been able to target the first value using regex with something like, `(?<=tags: )`.

I can't figure out how to get the rest of the line and what to do with it from there.

Comment: So every markdown file has the same format? Or at least the tags line always starts with tags?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see evidence of your effort. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you which is not the Stack Overflow way.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the line always starts with `tags:`, you could do the following:

```
with open('data.md') as fin:  # change to your file path
    with open('result.md', 'w') as fou:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('tags:'):
                tags = line.split(':')[1].split()
                line = f'tags: {tags}\n'
            fou.write(line)
```

**Output** *(result.md)*

```
---
layout: post
title: "Blog title"
date: 2016-02-24 09:39:00 -0500
tags: ['work', 'career', 'code', 'programming']
layout: post
---
```

The idea is to transform the line into a list using [split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and write it back using the list string representation.

If you need the strings to wrapped in double-quotes you could use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), like:

```
import json

with open('data.md') as fin:  # change to your file path
    with open('result.md', 'w') as fou:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('tags:'):
                tags = json.dumps(line.split(':')[1].split())
                line = f'tags: {tags}\n'
            fou.write(line)
```

**Output** *(with double-quotes)*

```
---
layout: post
title: "Blog title"
date: 2016-02-24 09:39:00 -0500
tags: ["work", "career", "code", "programming"]
layout: post
---
```